# How to put 2 php codes in functions.php without site crashing

Tags: php, functions, menus, post-thumbnails, code

I can use either the php script for a menu

```
<!-- menu -->
<?php function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' ); ?>
```

or the post thumbnail script

```
<!-- post thumbnails -->
<?php add_theme_support('post-thumbnails') ?>
```

But when I use both under eachother (like the above) then I can't update my custom theme editor anymore. Is there a way to seperate these codes that I don't know of? My php knowledge is 0..

Comment: I use a custom wordpress theme that i created myself

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely with your [PHP opening and closing tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) (these things: `<?php`, `?>`. If you have an open PHP tag, `<?php`, and then try to add another one, you will cause a fatal error.

It's important with your PHP files to keep track of your PHP tags so that they're balanced, just like HTML tags need to be. For a standard functions.php file you likely only need a single PHP tag at the very beginning (you shouldn't use a closing PHP tag if it's the end of the file):

```
<?php
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );

function wpb_theme_supports() {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpb_theme_supports' );
```

Note that `add_theme_support()` needs to be within a function that's hooked on `after_setup_theme`. Also, don't put HTML comments in your functions file like that. It will always be output and will likely cause headers related errors.

Comment: I will try this, and the comments I put there for stackexchange but thanks, i noticed that the hard way